# Get back to original content of a div by clicking on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I managed to change the content of my div by a click on it, but I don't know how to get back to the original content of this div by a second click.

http://jsfiddle.net/8c9hL9xm/1/

At the first click, the content changes from "CLICK" to "CLICK2",
at the second click, the content doesn't change to "CLICK".

Html :

```
<div class="button"><a href="#link1">CLICK</a></div>
```

Script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.button').click(function() {
      $(this).html('<a href="#link2">CLICK2</a>');
   });
});
```

Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: If it only has to do with 2 value you can use `if (...) {} else {}`. So you have to check if the value is `CLICK` then make it `CLICK2` else make it `CLICK`.

Comment: Because you did not code it to work that way...

Comment: Save the old contents in a variable, and then put it back on the second click.

Comment: I tried it but doesn't work, or I missed something. The answer of @undefined works good. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code resets the html content of the clicked element on each click, toggling content of an element is not the `html` method's default behavior. Instead of resetting `innerHTML` of the element, you can change the properties of the `a` child:

```
$('.button').click(function () {
    $(this).children('a').attr('href', function (_, currentHref) {
        return currentHref === '#link1' ? '#link2' : '#link1';
    }).text(function (_, currentText) {
        return currentText === 'CLICK' ? 'CLICK2' : 'CLICK1';
    });
});
```

You can also use the `toggle` or `toggleClass` method:

```
<div class="button">
    <a href="#link1">CLICK</a>
    <a href="#link2" class='hidden'>CLICK2</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.button').click(function () {
    $(this).children('a').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function() {
        if($(this).html().indexOf("CLICK2") > 0){
            $(this).html('<a href="#link">CLICK</a>');
        } else {
            $(this).html('<a href="#link2">CLICK</a>');
        }
    });
});
```

Or use a REGEX statement to check with kind of content you are dealing of.

Answer (score 1):

Using an array of contents?

```
var i = 0,
contents = ['<a href="#link1">CLICK</a>', '<a href="#link2">CLICK2</a>'];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.button').click(function () {
        (i < contents.length - 1) ? i++ : i = 0;
        $(this).html(contents[i]);
    });
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8c9hL9xm/4/)**